# Need help to get JSON data from warframe game

Tags: javascript, json

any idea with this is not working?

```
var xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
var url = "http://content.warframe.com/dynamic/worldState.php";
xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
    if (xmlhttp.readyState == 4 && xmlhttp.status == 200) {
        var myArr = JSON.parse(xmlhttp.responseText);
        myFunction(myArr);
    }
};
xmlhttp.open("GET", url, true);
xmlhttp.send();

function myFunction(arr) {
}
```

everytime i get `status = 0`.
i use the same method to get my script working with the twitch one, but can't get this one working.

thank for your help guys.

edit : ok thanks any idea what can i do to get the data from this site then?(if someone have any idea it will be awesome. as you can guess i can't edit the page who provide the date, but i know some people are able to get the JSON data) .

Comment: sees to be CORS issue - XMLHttpRequest cannot load http://content.warframe.com/dynamic/worldState.php. No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource.

Comment: Try adding some console.log to see whether it is working fine or not from your side by adding below to myFunction
function myFunction(arr) {
console.log(arr);
}

Comment: If you check your browser's development tools and looked at the network panel, it should have shown you that error.  http://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/8525/how-to-open-the-javascript-console-in-different-browsers